# ViewChild component undefined when trying to call method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, viewchild

I am retrieving data from a db and data is ready I am trying to bind to a child element by using ViewChild so as to pass obj data to the child element

The issue is that the component is not "ready" so I set a timeout of 2 seconds.

This doesn't feel right. How would I know if the child component is ready.

**Parent component retrieves data from the DB**

```
 @ViewChild("assumps") assumps: AssumptionsComponent
 getProposalAmounts() {
    this.targets.getProposalAmounts().subscribe((data) => {
    this.assumptions = data.assumptions;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.assumps.setAssumptionsForm(this.assumptions);
    }, 2000)
```

**Inside the child component**

```
setAssumptionsForm(obj: Assumptions) {
if (obj != null) {
  this.assumptionsObj = obj;
}
```

Without the timeout the child in null;
Error reads `Cannot read property 'setAssumptionsForm' of undefined`

Thank you

Comment: Could you show us the html  where the child appears?

Comment: you can check if the child component is ready in the `ngAfterViewInit` and then, when is ready ( `if(!!this.assumps)`) do your logic

Comment: when  getProposalAmounts() is called? And how child component is created?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a service for your component and subscribe to it. When you child constructor is executed you emit an event for your service letting the parent know that he is ready.

That seems to me the best solution.

Another way is to pass your data as input for your child component and create a loader for when your data is missing.

I actually prefere the first one, since it is a more reusable approach :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're expecting to render `assumps` template as soon as you assign `this.assumptions` value, and expecting to render that DOM instantly. But it doesn't happen in that way. Correct me if my assumptions are wrong.

Rather you can consider creating [`QueryList`](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList)(special Observable) of `AssumptionsComponent` when you did `ViewChild` query. And later you can keep eye on `QueryList` Observable `changes` property. Thereafter you can directly get the changes(DOM removal and addition) happening over `#assumps` template variable.

```
@ViewChild("assumps") assumps: QueryList<AssumptionsComponent>;


getProposalAmounts() {
    this.targets.getProposalAmounts().subscribe((data) => {
    this.assumptions = data.assumptions;
}

ngOnInit () {
    this.assumps.changes((list) => {
        list.forEach(assump => 
          assump.setAssumptionsForm(this.assumptions)
        )
    })        
}
```